# best way of tqdm for data loader

Tags: python, pytorch, tqdm

How to use tqdm for data_loader ?

is this the correct way?

```
for i,j in enumerate(data_loader,total = 100):
           pass
```

Comment: you mean the progress bar?

Comment: Yes the progress bar

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to wrap the iterable with tqdm, as their documentation clearly says:

> Instantly make your loops show a smart progress meter - just wrap any
> iterable with tqdm(iterable), and you’re done!

If you're enumerating over an iterable, you can do something like the following. Sleep is only for visualizing it.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

data_loader = list(range(1000))

for i, j in enumerate(tqdm(data_loader)):
    sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `enumerate` with `tqdm`, you can use it this way:

```
for i,data in enumerate(tqdm(train_dataloader)):
    images, labels = data 
    images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
    ....
```